# Error Column count doesn't value count at row 1

Tags: php, sql

I have a sub in my sql file

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJGb1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define in which column which value you insert. For example, INSERT INTO 'table_name' (column_1, column_2) VALUES(1, "hello").
More INSERT INTO syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: hello I found the problem in party I found 2 admin table I deleted an etsamarche